# Error passing json data through ajax method into DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Im getting an error in my IDE on the console of Google Chrome that states: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.` This error is thrown when `dataTables` takes the raw json data and attempts to inject it into the table.

```
 // Got the data - add it to the table
for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ ) {
_fnAddData( settings, aData[i] );
}

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){

    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqHXR ){
        options.async = true;
    });

$.ajax({
    //type: 'GET',
    url: 'URL',
    dataType:"json",
    data: "getAddressResults", //name of json expression
    success: function(data){
    var jsTable = $('#data').dataTable();
    jsTable.fnClearTable();

    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        var i = this.length;
        alert("There are : " + i + " entries."); //shows how many objects are in my json data 

    jsTable.dataTable().fnAddData([
        value[key].childName,
        value[key].childNum,
        value[key].lineNum,
        value[key].parentName,
        value[key].parentNum
    ]);
});
        if(data){
            var txt = "";
            if(res > 0){
                for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                if (data[i].parentNum && data[i].childNum){
                    txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].parentNum+"</td><td>"+data[i].childNum+"</td></tr>"
                }
            }
            if(txt !=""){
                $("#data").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
            }
        }
    }
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        }       
    });
        return false;
});


    $('#data').DataTable({
    columns:[
        { title: "childName" },
        { title: "childNum" },
        { title: "lineNum" },
        { title: "parentName" },
        { title: "parentNum" }
        ]
});
```

Comment: // Got the data - add it to the table
     for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ ) {
      _fnAddData( settings, aData[i] );}

That is the line that gives the error, length being undefined.

Comment: Where is `aData` defined?

Comment: aData is something the the jquery plugin dataTables makes and defines, thats the issue Im having is Im not sure exactly what it pulls from my code to then define aData.

Answer (score -1):

Remove that `<script>` tag, you can't just put an html tag like that in between of a javascript.

Comment: Top piece of code is in the resulting jquery that datatables puts out, and that's the part where the error occurs. The script tag is because Im rendering javascript on the HTML page so it has to be contained within the <script></script> tags. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1735921 this is not an answer. it should be placed as comment.